# How to prioritize the matched pattern in java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a text to match from a list of pattern.
Everything is fine until that text matches with 2 or more patterns

for example

**List of Patterns**

```
ABCD*
ABC*E
ABC*
AB*
```

And my string is **ABCDE** ,so it maches with all the patterns. what I would like to have is that since the nearest match is ( using [levenstein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm)

```
ABCD*
ABC*D
```

I want ABCD* to be selected a the closest match.

I am out of Ideas, I don't need the code , I just need the logic on how to achieve this.

Comment: Maybe related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086332/levenshtein-distance-in-regular-expression

Comment: Levenshtein distance does not apply to regular expressions, what you would need is some sort of metric like the required backtracks like in http://www.regexbuddy.com/debug.html but Java does not expose those internals so you would probably have to write your own regex parser that does or find a different approach / alternative regex implementation.

Comment: Is it too expensive for you to compute your distance metric for each pattern that matches and just take the "closest" match for your definition of "closest?"

Comment: If the set of patterns has some structure, you can presort patterns by descending priority and pick the first match. In this particular example number of consecutive uppercase letters can be used to sort patterns. In general case, it'd be better to use a metric as suggested by @merlin2011.