# android java regex match all but one character

Tags: java, android, regex, csv

I have a CSV database which contains names, addresses etc.

Now I will search in my Android App for something, let's say the address and then display the other records associated with it - name, phone...

The problem is, that in the CSV some of the entries are with missing characters, and there are white spaces instead - for example "G rmany Dresden" (with white space instead of "e")

Unfortunately, the database is frequently updated and I cannot correct it every time manually.

How can I match "Germany Dresden", "G rmany Dresden", "Germa y Dresden" etc when I search for "Germany"?

I suppose there has to be a limit of mismatched characters, so let's assume there are no more than two - at least I never saw more than that

Comment: You need a more precise definition of what to match. Since `Germa y` is a suitable match for `Germany`, is `G` a suitable match too? What is exactly a suitable match in your situation?

Comment: the last edit was wrong - see updated revision

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is Levenshtein distance (you're looking for something with a distance of 1 from Germany, aside from insertions and deletions). You can't do it directly with a regex, but you could generate the regex programmatically.

There's another answer here that might be of use: [Levenshtein distance in regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086332/levenshtein-distance-in-regular-expression)

Comment: Never knew about Levenshtein distance, thank you for the info :)