# How to find minimum replacement strings or regex to convert string to another string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, .net-4.6

Ok the title may be not correct but this is what i came as best

My question is this

Example 1

`see` , `saw`

I can convert `see` to `saw` with as

replace `ee` with `aw`

```
        string srA = "see";
        string srB = "saw";

        srA = srB.Replace("aw", "ee");
```

Or lets say

`show` , `shown`

add `n` to original string

Now what i want it is, with minimum length of code, generating such procedures to any compared strings

Looking for your ideas how can i make it? Can i generate regexes automatically to apply and convert?

c# 6

Comment: The general concept is referred to as [Edit Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever how are you going to apply edit distance to automatically convert 1 into another :)

Comment: I was pointing out that this general concept has a name and pointing you towards it. For the actual problem you're trying to solve, I guess it doesn't make much sense to me at the moment - if you've got two specific strings, knowing *how* you could transform between them makes some kind of sense but generating code that *will* perform the transformation doesn't much, to me - because you already have the end result of that transformation.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever how it make sense is like this. consider that there are millions of strings and many of them requires same operations. so i can define operations and give them ID. instead of saving entire operation or 1 on 1 saving, i can only save ID of the operation for that particular string. this would save huge space

Answer (score 1):

Check [diffplex](https://github.com/mmanela/diffplex) and and see if it is what you need. If you want to create a custom algorithm, instead of using a 3rd party library just go through the code -it's open source.

You might also want to check [this](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3284.html) work for optimizations, but it might get complicated.

Then there's also [Diff.NET](http://menees.com/index.html).

Also [this blog post](http://devdirective.com/post/91/creating-a-reusable-though-simple-diff-implementation-in-csharp-part-1) is part of a series in implementing a diff tool.

If you're simply interested in learning more about the subject, your googling efforts should be directed to the **Levenshtein algorithm**.

I can only assume what your end goal is, and the time you're willing to invest in this, but I believe the first library should be enough for most needs.

Comment: Ty for the answer. I am really at the space limitation so i need to store operation with minimalism. Like the function replace or a regex.  If there were a regex builder that would be super cool.

Comment: Judging by this answer, none exists, unfortunately http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086332/levenshtein-distance-in-regular-expression