# How can we capture "near-misses" in a SQL stored procedure that finds matches between 2 tables using join logic?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have the following schema:

```
-- Table A DDL
create table DataSourceA
(
    ID bigint identity(1, 1),
    TextData varchar(30)
)

-- Table B DDL
create table DataSourceB
(
    ID bigint identity(1, 1),
    TextData varchar(30)
)
```

And the stored procedure has a join based on string-based matching

```
-- Query in stored procedure
select *
from DataSourceA a
inner join DataSourceB b
    on substring(a.TextData, 1, 3) = substring(b.TextData, 3, 3)
```

What would be a good way to also capture near misses?

One way I can think of is this:

```
-- Capture near misses (not optimized, since it's just to demonstrate intent)
select *
from (
    -- All non-matches
    select a.ID as a_id, 
        b.ID as b_id, 
        a.TextData as a_text, 
        b.TextData as b_text
    from DataSourceA a
    cross join DataSourceB b
    except
    select *
    from #ResultsOfTheActualMatches
) non_matches
where substring(b_text, 3, 2) = substring(a_text, 1, 2)  -- match off by 1 character
    or substring(b_text, 3, 1) = substring(a_text, 1, 1) -- match off by 2 characters etc...
```

The challenge is that this gets out of hand really quickly. Plus, the developer has to manually think up all possible cases of near-misses. What if the join condition has more complex logic (like charindex, replace, pattern-matching etc)?

There may be some ways using some text-based algorithm...

```
-- Find matches and near-misses using Levenshtein distance (seems simple for this specific example)
select a.ID as a_id,
    b.ID as b_id,
    a.TextData as a_text,
    b.TextData as b_text,
    case when dbo.Levenshtein(substring(a_text, 1, 3), substring(b_text, 3, 3)) = 0 then 'match'
        when dbo.Levenshtein(substring(a_text, 1, 3), substring(b_text, 3, 3)) = 1 then 'near-miss-1'
        when dbo.Levenshtein(substring(a_text, 1, 3), substring(b_text, 3, 3)) = 2 then 'near-miss-2'
        else 'miss'
    end as match_status
from DataSourceA a
cross join DataSourceB b
```

But, what I am interested in is how to handle the general case here? For instance, what would be a general approach to log near-misses for the following text condition?

```
select *
from DataSourceA a
inner join DataSourceB b
    on
-- More complicated join condition
(substring(a.TextData, 1, 3) = substring(b.TextData, 3, 3) and a.TextData not like '%[0-9]$')
or
(substring(a.TextData, 1, 3) = substring(b.TextData, 3, 3) and replace(b.TextData, substring(a.TextData, 7, 1), 'X') not like '%[0-9][A-Z]$')
```

Comment: Please update your question and add example data that you are needed

Comment: Have you considered Soundex? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/soundex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Have you looked up any "edit distance" functions?

Comment: @Nugsson Phonetic algorithms look to be in the right direction! Although I think for this use case, it is a bit tangential (at least Soundex). For instance, soundex for 'fare' and 'fair' has the same encoding, whereas a substring-based match condition might not match.

Comment: @shawnt00 yes, see my example above using Levenshtein distance. Actually, based on your comment, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086332/levenshtein-distance-in-regular-expression) that asks for a way to apply edit distance to regex. That may be the key.

Comment: Please give more details on what you consider a "near miss"?